# How to fully uninstall Kite? (windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, visual-studio-code, sublime-text-3

I had installed Kite on the completion of anacondas installation (on Windows 10). Then I noticed that Spyder was badly (and I mean badly) lagging. I suspected it was because of Kite because Spyder had been running smoothly when I had first installed anaconda without Kite. So, I uninstalled Kite.

**But**, even after uninstallation, every time I launch VS Code or Sublime Text, I get annoying pop-up messages suggesting installation of Kite. I looked into the settings of both editors, but couldn't find any mention of Kite. How do I get rid of this ghost of Kite?